# JWT Nodejs-Accessing payload data in another file using Decode

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a controllerfile where I use passport.authenticate. I declare my payload and sign my token now i need the info declared in the payload in another file so I could use them in my sql request.
Here's the code for the login auth :

```
login: (req, res, next) => {
console.log(" login");
passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }, (error, user) => {
    console.log("executing callback auth * from authenticate for local strategy ");

    //if there was an error in the verify callback related to the user data query 
    if (error || !user) {
        next(new error_types.Error404("Email ou Mot de passe invalide !"))
    }else {
        console.log("*** Token generation begins ***** ");
        console.log(user)
        const payload = {
            sub: user.id,
            exp: Date.now() + parseInt(process.env.JWT_LIFETIME),
            email: user.email,
            name: user.prenom,
            lastName: user.nom,
            type:user.type,
        };

        
        const token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(payload), process.env.JWT_SECRET, {algorithm: process.env.JWT_ALGORITHM});
        res.json({ token: token,type: user.type,userid:user.id  });//added userid
    }

})(req, res);
 }
```

Now in my other file i need to get the user.id and user.type so that i could use them in my request :

```
const createProp=(req, res, next) => {
 let con=req.con

let { xx,yy } = req.body;
con.query('INSERT INTO tab1 
(xx,yy,user_id,user_type ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ',[xx,yy,user_id,user_type],
(err, results) => {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   res.status(404).json({error: err});
 }
 else
 {res.status(200).send(`success`)}
  }
 );

 }
```

in my frontend VUEJS this is my file:

```
   import router from '@/router'
   import { notification } from 'ant-design-vue'
    import JwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
   import apiClient from '@/services/axios'
   import * as jwt from '@/services/jwt'
 const handleFinish = (values) => {
  const formData = new FormData()
  for (var key of Object.keys(formState)) {
    formData.append(key, formState[key])//here im appending some fields in my         
          //form i have more than just xx,yy files i just put them as an 
          //example
  }
  const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken"); 
        var decoded = JwtDecode(token);
        console.log(decoded)
  formData.append('user_id',decoded.sub)
  formData.append('user_type',decoded.type)     
  fileListFaisabilite.value.forEach((file) => {
    formData.append('xx', file)
  })
  fileListEvaluation.value.forEach((file) => {
    formData.append('yy', file)
  })
  
 // store.dispatch('user/PROPOSITION', formData)
}
 methods:{
 PROPOSITION({ commit, dispatch, rootState  }, formData ) {
  commit('SET_STATE', {
    loading: true,
  })
const proposition= 
 mapAuthProviders[rootState.settings.authProvider].proposition

  proposition(formData)
    .then(success => {
      if (success) {
        
        notification.success({
          message: "Succesful ",
          description: " form submited!",
        })
        router.push('/Accueil')
        commit('SET_STATE', {
          loading: false,
        })
      }
      if (!success) {
        commit('SET_STATE', {
          loading: false,
        })
      }
    })
 return  apiClient 
.post('/proposition', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
     },
      })
  .then(response => {
     if (response) {
      
    return response.data
  }
  return false
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)) 
},


 
},
```

What im looking for is how i can store in my database the userid and usertype using insertinto sql request.

Answer (score 0):

You can set user data in your jwt sign function without stringify method:

```js
const payload = {
  sub: user.id,
  exp: Date.now() + parseInt(process.env.JWT_LIFETIME),
  email: user.email,
  name: user.prenom,
  lastName: user.nom,
  type: user.type // <-- Add this
};

        
const token = jwt.sign(
  payload, // Don't use JSON.stringify
  process.env.JWT_SECRET, 
  {algorithm: process.env.JWT_ALGORITHM}
);
```

And access user info:

```js
jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, payload) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
    }

    // Get some data
    let user_id = payload.sub;
    let user_type = payload.type;
    console.log(user_id, user_type);

    next();
});
```

The vue file:

```js
PROP({ commit, dispatch, rootState  }, payload ) {
  
  commit('SET_STATE', {
    loading: true,
  });
  const prop = mapAuthProviders[rootState.settings.authProvider].prop

  prop(payload)
    .then(success => {
      if (success) {
        // success contains user information and token:
        const { token, userid, type } = success;
        
        // Save to localStorage (Optional)
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
        localStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
        localStorage.setItem("type", type);

        // This not works if don't have a JWT SEED
        // var decoded = JwtDecode(token);

        commit('SET_STATE', {
          user_id: userid,
          user_type: type,
        })
        //dispatch('LOAD_CURRENT_ACCOUNT')
        notification.success({
          message: "Succesful ",
          description: " form submited!",
        })

        router.push('/Home')
        commit('SET_STATE', {
          loading: false,
        })
      }
      if (!success) {
        commit('SET_STATE', {
          loading: false,
        })
      }
    })
},
```

The api call file:

```js
export async function prop(payload) {
 try {
    const response = await apiClient.post('/prop', payload, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    });

    if (response) {
        return response.data;
    }

 } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
 }

 return false; 
}
```

Comment: The part where u use jwt.verify, i can use it in the other file where im creating my model? I don't want to use it in the same file as the one where i use passport

Comment: Yes, you can send `jwt.verify` to another file and hanlde the error or success token verification via callback.

Comment: now i did some changes i did not use jwt.verify i used decode in my front side (vuejs) and now i want to use user_id and user_type in my sql idk how, the thing is i have two type of users i want to get their id and their type in my new tab1

Comment: If you send the token to the bakend, with decodification can get the user information that you stored. In front-side, you should send `user_id` and `user_type` in you `res.json` method like that: `res.json({ token: token, type: user.type, userId: user.id  });`

Comment: i just edited my code added what i have in front and added in my back the userid in res.json , what i want here is to stock the userid and usertype idk how to do that

Comment: the whole story is i form that can be submited either by user type1 or user type2 (2 different tables user1 and user2) so now i want in my new table to stock the info of the form plus the id of user and his type

Comment: Ok, i updated my response with some fixes on you vue file and api call.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are doing a multipart request, so make sure you are receiving the information on the backend and the correct response on the front.

Comment: thank u but how can i lake the sql request , because the forl that i have when submited i do get everything in place correctly but the field of user_type and user_id is empty

Comment: The `user_id` and `user_type` in `createProp` function isn't defined. Get it in `req` sending from api call file in your front the userid, user type or, don't send this attrs but use `jwt.verify` to get the user data.

Comment: im passing them in the form data userid and usertype and thay are stocked in payload of the apicall

Comment: idk how to insert my values in my tab1 while stocking userid of one of my users(from another table) and my usertype

Comment: Can't send the userid and usertype as parameters or in `req` object?

Comment: i can send them in req.body i have that missed in my code but nothing happens i should make a controll to check if it's user1 then stock userid and his type else the info of user2 idk how to make that

Comment: I don't understand. You have two users (user1 & user2)?

Comment: i have two type of users so two different tables in db each one has their own info now in each of these tables i have id , in my new tab i want to insert the id of the user who filled the form also his type thanks to usertype and userid

Comment: Ok. i.e. I send in the submitted form the userid: 1, and type: user1, the query inserts in table `user1` the userid (1), usertype (user1)?

Comment: the query inserts in table tab1 like not in the table of the user but another one and this table will have all the forms submitted from user1 and user2 so it gets his id and type

Comment: Can you add an `if` statement condition?

Comment: idk what to put in it ,i don't know how to use user_type to check with it

Comment: Simple `if (user_type === 'type_A') { // sql query when type is 'type_A'} else if (user_type === 'type_B') { // sql query when type is 'type_B'  } else if ...`?

Comment: i just tested if i put user_id and user_type in req.body i get an error

Comment: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined)  this error in my browsers console and this error in my vscode terminal :invalid input syntax for type integer: "" (note that type is defined as string in db)

Comment: Debug the `createprop` function and check the values for `xx,yy,user_id,user_type` after `conn.query(...)` statement.

Comment: the xx yy (fields of form i get their value back but i get nothin for user_id and user_type i no longer get error but the submit button stays loading with nothing to happen

Comment: im sorry for disturbing you , thank u for your time it's already 1am here im super tired , i tried everything but it's not working for me tomorrow will repeat and see if i can make it owrk

Comment: The problem I think is perhaps because the user_id and user_type values are not being sent

Comment: yeaah that's the problem i guess

Comment: You could try to track the information from the moment it is sent from the form to the server. If you use Chrome or Mozilla you can see the information being sent in the dev tools->network.

Comment: idk how i can make them being sent i did everything withe passing them in the form data so in the apicall i got them in the Prop function , idk what else should i do

Comment: `let { xx,yy } = req.body;` to `let { xx,yy,user_type, user_id } = req.body; console.log(user_type, user_id)`?

Comment: If not, send form as `application/json`. Multipart only if you send multipart data as a files.

Comment: nothing , the submit button stays on loading mode and nothing in console i added consolr.log("hello",user_id) to test i get the hello back nothing after it

Comment: i do have files in my form that's why th multipartfom

Comment: There can be two problems. The first is that you are not sending the information with those names in the form. The second is that you are trying to access that data without first having managed the multipart information. If you are using a manager for the files that you upload to the server, you must first upload them, otherwise you will not be able to access the parameters in the req.body.

Comment: An example is that you have the middleware to upload the files before the call to `createProp`.
app.post (
  "/ route-name",
[updloadFilesMiddleware],
createProp);

Comment: I have been testing and if said middleware is not called at the beginning, at least using body-parser and express, the body owns an empty object.

Comment: im using multer to handle upload file it works fine i tested it if i only insert xx,yy i get them uploaded and have their path in db it works just fine , the problem is user_id and usr_type

Comment: Umm. Can update the post with the form submittion parte and how Is user_id and user_type Is sended?

Comment: i did not include them in the req.body when i send the files but when i do include and just try the console.log() nothing appears

Comment: And  if you use console.log(req.body) what prints?

Comment: i eddited the post

Comment: Don't use for yo iterate formState. Add the user_id and user_type manually with formData.append('user_id', formState.user_id), and same for user_type.

Comment: [Object: null prototype] {
  user_id: '',
  user_type: '',
  xxFilePath: '/uploads/1618447569902_exp.PNG'
} i just uploaded one file that's why theres one filepath but userid and type ''

Comment: where do i add formData.append('user_id', formState.user_id)? after the for loop?

Comment: now i get user_id: 'undefined',
  user_type: 'undefined'

Comment: Add instead of for loop

Comment: And check after call atore.dispatch the values of formData. Can use formData.get(..) to get the values with the keys.

Comment: im thinking about putting all of my code of front in one file can u help me out that way? like the apicall the function prop and the form all in one file

Comment: i updated the post so now all the code happens where i define my form that's the part below my form where i pass my data in the formState and stuff now i have when i run it nothing happens ,the form isn't submited at all

Comment: Then`fileListEvaluation.value.forEach((file) => {
    formData.append('yy', file)
  })` can you print the formData values?

Comment: i don't have problem with files it gets uploaded just fine with it's path and all

Comment: in backend when i do concole.log in prints fine the value of it

Comment: my only problem is how to pass the user_id and user_type from front to back

Comment: But in formData you send the user_id and user_type. Check if has some values or not, because in backend side doesn't appear

Comment: nothing appears i accually did console.log("hello",user_id) under my let{xx,yy,user_id,user,type)} in my backend file and nothing appeared not even the hello word

Comment: the code that i have in methods part is it correct? i copied what i had in different files and put it toghether now nothing works like if i press the submitt button nothing happens

Comment: And what prints `console.log(formData.get("user_id"))` in front side (after submitting the form)?

Comment: nothing is shown i puut under formappend(user_id) i put also after all appends nothing is shown no error no warrning and still not working

Comment: Ow, I'm really not sure where the error occurs. Apparently it is something in the front. You should start debugging from somewhere where it works fine.

Comment: yeah thanks for your time it seems pretty messed up idk how Im gonna make it work but thanks :)